# Is multiple inheritance allowed in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, class, extend

When go through the core source, I figured out that some classes have been extended by many child classes.

Eg:

```
   class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract

   class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
```

Is this allowed for any class or only for some classes?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think that's the point of inheritance in general. You can have one base class and multiple children. Note: Most of the classes in Magento are children (or grandchildren and so on) of `Varien_Object`

Comment: But I don't think that we can extend all the classes in Magento

Comment: I think you question is a bit unclear then. Maybe you should ad an example of what you are trying to achieve. In theory you can extend any class if it's not declared as `final` (as the `Mage` class is declared). Maybe the problem is how you use those child classes.

Comment: I mean for example Observers you cannot extend right?

Comment: You can check this SO post for clarification : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501536/magento-multiple-classes-extending-same-core-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you meaning rewrite (a model), rather than extend (a class)?

Rewrite != extend. Two very different conventions.

You can extend any class, as this is basic OOP convention. (unless it is a final declared class) 
You cannot rewrite all magento classes (or rather models).

If you rewrite a model, you would also extend its class (but don't always have to, depending on what functionality you are doing, but usually you will), but if you extend a class, you do not need to rewrite it (as an example, I have a module that adds product functionality, thus I can extend the core product classes to inherit their methods)

You can extend magento observers just fine, as that is OOP. If you want to replace (rewrite) functionality in another observer (be it core or 3rd party), here is a way to do it:

1. Make your module depend on the other. This ensures it is loaded before yours, and its event listener is loaded.
2. You listen to the same event, but in your event declaration, you disable the other modules listener. This ensures only your listener is used, and not both.
3. Make sure your observer extends the other modules observer.

The end result is that only your module's observer will run when the event is fired, BUT since you extended the other modules observer, it's code will also run. This way you can override its methods with your own code.

As an example:
I have to extend the magemonkey module observer code, and change the code of a method in it's observer.

The magemonkey module event is newsletter_subscriber_save_before

My module will thus have this declaration:

```
   <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
        <observers>
            <monkey_subscribe_observer>
                <type>disabled</type>
            </monkey_subscribe_observer>
        </observers>
        <observers>
            <enhanced_newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
                <class>enhancedmonkey/observer</class>
                <method>handleSubscriber</method>
            </enhanced_newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
        </observers>
    </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
```

and my observer class extends their class:

```
class Doghouse_EnhancedMageMonkey_Model_Observer extends Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Model_Observer
```